# Git svn: how do I work with "partial" branches?

Tags: git, branch, git-svn

By "partial", I mean the branches in my SVN repository were not copied from trunk/, but from a subdirectory of trunk/.  Here's the svn repo layout:

```
trunk/
    core
    projectA
    projectB
    ...
branches/
    core_new_feature (branched from "core" on trunk)
    another_branch
    ...
```

I have inited my local repository and fetched:

```
mkdir git-svn-repo
cd git-svn-repo
git svn init -s svn+ssh://me@svn-server/path/to/repository
git fetch
<wait four days>
```

Now I'm trying to work on the "core_new_feature" branch.  git branch -a shows:

```
* master
remotes/core_new_feature
... (a bunch of other branches)
```

So I try:

```
git checkout --track -b git_new_feature remotes/core_new_feature
```

Git checks out files, and appears to be working. Yet when I try to browse my freshly checked out branch (ls local-git-root/core/), I get weirdness. Specifically, I don't see my source code or any of the existing changes on the core_new_feature SVN branch.  All I see under core/ are a few empty directories, a seemingly random smattering of my exiting source tree under core.

However, the "core_new_feature" source **is** available under local-git-root/src/ - it's just right there in the root of my git repository. projectA and projectB from above have disappeared.

What I need is for the changes on the "core_new_feature" svn branch to go to the correct location (namely local-git-root/core/), and for the other projects to not disappear

Clearly I'm missing some crucial step here, but I've looked through all the examples I could find, and none seems to deal with this issue. Maybe I need to set up my local repository differently?

For reference, here's my .git/config file:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
        symlinks = false
        ignorecase = true
        hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
        url = svn+ssh://me@svn-server/path/to/repository
        fetch = repository/trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
        branches = repository/branches/*:refs/remotes/*
        tags = repository/tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
[branch "core_new_feature"]
        remote = .
        merge = refs/remotes/core_new_feature
```

My repository uses the standard branches/ tags/ trunk/ layout.  I ran the commands using the git-bash shell that msysgit provides. Version is 1.7.4.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Can you please include the commands you used for performing the git-svn clone, as well as the contents of the .git/config file?

Comment: For the record: I never did end up solving this, so I'm leaving it unanswered.  It sucked, but I ended up forcing everyone to commit their code to trunk, and then did the full migrate to Git without any interim git-svn.  A bit painful but it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used git-svn myself, but markjaquith has a good post on how he uses it to manage his commits for his WordPress development. You might consider skimming it to see if he mentions anything useful. I've had it tucked away for the next time I update one of my WordPress plugins, or create a new one (everything WordPress is on svn).

http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/developing-on-wordpress-using-git/